# How do I change or replace the ImageCache in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to change the behavior of the ImageCache in my Flutter app. For example, I want to experiment with different eviction strategies. Or, I simply want zero caching (for experimenting).

How do I replace to change the ImageCache?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from WidgetsFlutterBinding.
Override createImageCache on that class to return the ImageCache implementation of your choice.
Call the constructor on that class before you call runApp.

---

There's one binding per application. The first binding (subclass of BindingBase) that is created gets to be that binding. Calling runApp() instantiates the WidgetsFlutterBinding binding, which is usually what you want. One of the classes that WidgetsFlutterBinding mixes in, the PaintingBinding, introduces createImageCache as a way to let you override the image cache. It calls that method, and sets the global imageCache to whatever that method returns.

Comment: I highly doubt it. The `ImageCache` used by `ImageProvider` including `AssetImageProvider` and stuff use the global `imageCache`. And that global is instantiated using `final ImageCache imageCache = new ImageCache();` . Since it's final, you can't change it.

Comment: In fact, looking in the source code `ServiceBinding` doesn't even have a `createImageCache`

Comment: My bad, there's a new alpha version which change how `imageCache` is instantiated. On the other hand, it's not `ServicesBinding`, but `PaintingBinding`

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad. Fixed the name of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Code snippet for Ian Hickson's proposal:

```
 import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

    class CustomImageCache extends WidgetsFlutterBinding {
      @override
      ImageCache createImageCache() {
        // Set your image cache size
        this.imageCache.maximumSize = 10;
        return super.createImageCache();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can't understand where and how it must be used. Can you explain a little bit, please?

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue with images cache. Flutter team fixed this issue, as I know. Anyway if you need it, just initialize `CustomImageCache` in `main` function.

Comment: if I initialize CustomImageCache in main fn, it gives me an error which says something like “Calling maximumSize on null”

Comment: May I ask you why do you need to do this now? Back in the days, Flutter had a bug with ImageCaches. It was fixed a long time ago.