# White flash when image is repainted [flutter]

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-image

I'm trying to build a grid of images with a given width and height, wrapping them inside `Containers` and using `fit: BoxFit.fill` to be able to set a border if the image is selected (i don't care to keep the image aspect ratio, i want to have the same total width and height for each container).

The problem is that i notice a white flash when the image gets repainted after it has been tapped on.
This seems not to happen when there are few images, but with 15+ images it is noisy.

I tried to add `gaplessPlayback: true` on the image widget, as i found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33641), but this did not solve my issue.

Here's a gif that shows my issue (i used 16 images, size is 1920x1080):

**EDIT:**

I forgot to point out that this is just an example, i used a border in the code but in my case i want also to add a padding to the container to make the image smaller (like in android photo gallery), this means that the tapped image should repaint every time.

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#target-platform-override
  debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: ImageGridView()),
    );
  }
}

class ImageGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  List<File> _fileList = [];
  ImageGridView(){
    _fileList = [
        File('C:/flutter/img/1.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/3.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/4.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/5.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/6.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/7.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/8.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/9.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/10.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/11.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/12.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/13.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/14.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/15.jpg'),
        File('C:/flutter/img/16.jpg'),
      ];
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Wrap(
        children: _fileList.map((file) {
          return WindowsAsset(file);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WindowsAsset extends StatefulWidget {
  final File _file;

  WindowsAsset(this._file);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => WindowsAssetState();
}

class WindowsAssetState extends State<WindowsAsset> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
    final height = width * 1080 / 1920;
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Container(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          decoration: !selected
              ? null
              : BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(153, 209, 255, 1),
                    width: 4
                  ),
                ),
          child: Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Image.file(
                widget._file,
                filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                gaplessPlayback: true,
              ),
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                selected = !selected;
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How i can solve it? Thank you!

Comment: i think you should use stack and draw a container over your image instead of change image parent container border

Comment: @veneno Thanks for your comment, i forgot to point out that mine was just an example, i used just a border in the code but in my case i want also to add a padding to the container, this means that the tapped image should repaint every time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because of a mix of 1. ImageCache constraints and 2. Nesting all your images within `Wrap`

The ImageCache has a maximum number of images that it can cache in memory, as well as a maximum number of total bytes. When that limit is reached, old images are evicted to make space for new ones. When trying to display an image that was previously evicted from cache, it will take some time to load it into memory again, therefore the white flash. You can change the limits of the cache as per [How do I change or replace the ImageCache in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836539/how-do-i-change-or-replace-the-imagecache-in-flutter/47840716)

The default image cache limits are 1000 different images and a total of 100MiB, which are usually enough given an optimal layout where off-screen widgets are not built.

`Wrap` might be the main reason of your problem - I believe it internally builds all of its children in order to figure out how to wrap them. In your case, that would be all of the images. It may be that because of the `Wrap`, all your images are considered on-screen and therefore not evicted from cache - this would explain why some of the images in the GIF are flashing even though you are not rebuilding the entire widget tree - because those images are not cached because the cache is full and none of the images can be evicted.

You might want to replace `Wrap` with a `GridView.builder`, which will only build the on-screen widgets.

You could have the same issue if the images are simply too large to fit as many in the cache as you are displaying at once. If you display a 50MB image in a 10x10 container, that still takes 50MB of in-memory cache.

Comment: Thank for your answer and explanation, i will try your solution and let you know!

Comment: I tried using GridView.builder method, but the result is the same. However, I'm playing a bit with ImageCache right now, do you think that Image.file caches images by default? If I use the code in the link you posted and I print imageCache.maximumSizeBytes it tells me that it is already 100MB (1000 total images), so i should not have any issue since I'm using 16 images and the total amount size is around 10MB

Comment: Yes all `Image` constructors will result in the images being cached, including `Image.file`. Try checking the values of `currentSize` and `currentSizeBytes` of the `ImageCache` when tapping on the images - this will clarify whether the issue is the `ImageCache` or something else.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but currentSizeBytes was larger than 100 MB even if the total size of the images is around 10 MB. If i set a huge maximum size the white flash disappears. I will consider this in future, thank you!

Comment: Setting the imageCache.maximumSizeBytes = 9999999999; worked for me!

Comment: FYI, I am using Wrap() with my images, and `gaplessPlayback: true` on the Image() widget solved my flickering.

Answer (score 34):

Set `gaplessPlayback` for your image to `true`.

```dart
Image.memory(
  thumbData,
  gaplessPlayback: true,
)
```

Comment: gaplessPlayback - whether to continue showing the old image (true), or briefly show nothing (false), when the image provider changes. The default value is false.

Comment: thanks for this however it didnt resolve my issue